# UIProgressView Not DIsplaying

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, opengl-es

I have a UIProgressView I want to run on my GLKViewController while the rest of the code is being loaded by iOS. I have placed the UIProgressView into my 'viewDidLoad' method. The UIProgressView does not display until all of the code has been loaded by the viewDidLoad method. How can I get the UIProgressView to display as soon as the viewDidLoad method is called and end when the viewDidLoad method is finished?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Progress Bar
    [threadProgressView setProgress: 0.0];    
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgressBar) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];

    // Disbale iPhone from locking
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES];

    // Set up context to use Open GL ES
    self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

    if (!self.context) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
    }

    // Create a view to display the Open GL ES content
    GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
    view.context = self.context;
    view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;

    /******** Default Settings **********/
    m_kf            = 0;                                    // The current keyframe ID.
    m_avPos         = GLKVector3Make(0.0f, 0.0f, -35.0f);   // Where to put the avata.
    m_camPos        = GLKVector3Make(0.0f, 10.0f, -35.0f);  // The camera orbits this point.
    m_camDist       = 30.0f;                                // Distance of camera from the orbit point.

    /******** Set up open gl ***********/
    [self setupGL];

    /********* TOUCH IMPLEMENTATION *********/

    // Pinch recongizer detects pinches and is used to zoom in/out
    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pinchDetected:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];

    // Pan recognizer, used to rotate around the x and y axis
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];

    /********* END TOUCH IMPLEMENTATION *********/

}
```

Comment: Is it placed on top of everything else ie using bringtofront, or through storyboard?

Comment: It is placed on told of all the other elements

Comment: Where you have added the ProgressView i.e in xib?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the UIProgressView to display as soon as the viewDidLoad method is called and end when the viewDidLoad method is finished?

When `viewDidLoad` is called the view is not yet on screen. After `viewDidLoad` you will see `viewWillAppear` then `viewDidAppear` being called.

And also if you have a long running `viewDidLoad` it will block your main thread, so your progress bar won't get updated.
When you do :

```
 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgressBar) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

Since you are on the main thread specifying `waitUntilDone` will queue up your request and it will process later, probably after your `viewDidLoad` have finish.

To do what you want to do, you will need more Asynchronous code.

Answer (score 0):

viewDidLoad is executed on main loop, main thread. That is the user interface thread. Any change on the interface will not be showed after it ends. So, it is normal behavior.

The selector updateProgressBar will be executed after viewDidLoad ends on the same thread (main thread).

Use viewDidLoad only for initialization, then execute process on a background thread and execute progressView changes on main thread (that is interface thread).

Answer (score 0):

On the main thread (which is your default) add:

```
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate: [NSDate distantPast]];
```

This will give the main loop a single shot, then return to your code.